# Command \itshape invalid in math mode

Tags: math-mode, macros, mode

how to correct it ?

```
  \noindent $~~~~~~~~ {\em 2) :} 
Supposons~ de~ plus~ que~ Z~ soit ~intégrable.~ 
Alors, ~pour 
    ~a,~b \in  \mathbb{R},$
```

Comment: How can anyone help you if you just _again_ post incomplete fragments with no indication what you want this to do. Start by removing every `~` and only having math in `$...$`

Comment: As it stands, you are trying to multiply the variables $S$, $u$, $p$ (twice), $o$, $s$, $o$ (again), $n$, $s$ (again), ....  Why are you doing this?

Comment: How to correct what?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item ...
\item Supposons de plus que $Z$ soit intégrable. Alors, pour 
    $a,b \in  \mathbb{R}$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```